# Switch Maximum and Minimum values in Two Dimensional Array

Tags: java

I'm trying to switch the minimum and maximum values of the array.

My code:

```
public static void swap(int[][] a, int i0, int j0, int i1, int j1) {
    int temp = a[i0][j0];
    a[i0][j0] = a[i1][j1];
    a[i1][j1] = temp;
  }
public static void main(String args[]){
    int max = 0, min = 0, tmpI = 0, tmpJ = 0, tmpI1 = 0, tmpJ1 = 0;
    int[][] a = {{10,9,20} , {2,10,10}};
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) { 
            if (min > a[i][j]) {
                min = a[i][j];
                tmpI1 = i; tmpJ1 = j;
            }
            if (max < a[i][j]) {
                max = a[i][j];
                tmpI = i; tmpJ = j;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
    swap(a,tmpI1,tmpJ1,tmpI,tmpJ);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
}
```

Output:

```
[[10, 9, 20], [2, 10, 10]]
[[20, 9, 10], [2, 10, 10]]
```

It is switching only to the first number for some reason. Any help? I'm new to java.

Comment: Change the initial value of `min` from `0` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I knew it had to be something small.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your initial value of `min` (`0`). When you say,

```
if (min > a[i][j]) {
```

it will never be true (because `0` is less than your numbers). Change the declaration of `min` to something like

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

because every `int` value will be less than that.